# iOS - how to forward touches to the underlying uiview

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, touch-event

I have 3 UIViews of the same size stacked on top of each other. The topmost is transparent and only used for detecting touches. The type of touch detected will determine which of the other two underlying views I want to receive the touch events. Once the topmost view is finished with the touch, I need to forward the touch events to the correct underlying view. How can I do that?

EDIT - I am adding my touch detection code. This is within MainViewController, whose view contains all 3 subviews.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        if (touch.view == self.touchOverlay) {
            CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

            //do a bunch of math to determine which view should get the touches.
            if (viewAshouldGetTouches) //forward to viewA
            if (viewBshouldGetTouches) //forward to viewB


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all of the UIView's subviews of a single view?

Comment: @Putz1103 yes they are subviews of a single view. I'm checking touchesMoved, etc. in the view controller than contains the views.

Answer (score 3):

Make your two subviews `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO` and handle all touches in the parent.  Then, depending on touch type, send the correct view a programatic touch event.  Then you don't need your clear view on the top.  Basically you will be coordinating touch events from the bottom up instead of going top->bottom->middle.

Comment: I have added my touchesMoved method above. Can you give an example of how to send one of the views a programmatic touch event from within touchesMoved? Basically the two views contain scroll views that need to scroll as normal if the view receives touch events.

Comment: Just call `[view1 touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` from inside touchesbegan.  I'm not certain that the scrollview will work properly using this, but in my head it should.

Comment: I need view1 to receive the touchesMoved events though, not touchesBegan. Calling touchesMoved from inside touchesMoved seems to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Does your "view1" call [super touchesMoved...]?  Because that would cause a problem.

Comment: no, view1 is not a subclass. It's just a view that is onscreen, under the overlay view.

Comment: Yup, then my answer is crap.  What you could do instead is have your "clear" view parse the touch events, and then have knowledge of it's superview's class and call the touches events inside the superview's class views.  Then make sure that setuserinteraction is enabled on all of the view.

Comment: Tried that. touchesMoved gets called in the view controller, but the scrollviews don't get the touch events.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do this by creating a UIView subclass for your top view and overriding the following method :

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // UIView will be "transparent" for touch events if we return NO
    return (point.y < MIDDLE_Y1 || point.y > MIDDLE_Y2);
}
```

Comment: But if I do that, can I still check the top view for touches in touchesMoved of the main view controller? That's where I determine which underlying view should get the touches.