# iOS - forward touches to another view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

There is a similar [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654557/ios-how-to-forward-touches-to-the-underlying-uiview) that exists for this problem but unfortunately there were no suitable answers provided.

I have a google maps view (GMSMapView) that is entirely covered by a transparent sibling view that acts as a container for thumbnail images. The thumbnails are child views of the container view, not the map view. These child views are randomly scattered about the map and therefore partially hide portions of the map's surface.

Tapping on one of these thumbnails triggers a segue to a different VC that shows a zoomed view of the image.

**The problem:**

Given that these thumbnails lie on top of the map, they prevent the normal map gestures from occurring if the gesture intersects one of the thumbnails. For example, if a user wishes to pinch-zoom, rotate or pan the map and one of his/her fingers begins overtop of a thumbnail, the touches are intercepted by the thumbnail.

**Non-starters:**

- Obviously, I can't set userInteractionEnabled to false on a thumbnail because I need to detect tap gestures to trigger the segue.
- I don't think that I can customize the responder chain using UIView's hitTest:withEvent and pointInside:withEvent methods on the thumbnail view because they are not in the same branch in the view hierarchy as the map view AND the dispatching logic is dependent on the type of gesture (which I don't think is available at this point - touchesBegan, etc. are called once the appropriate view has been chosen to receive the event). Please correct me if I'm wrong...

**Attempted Solution:**

Given the above, the strategy I'm attempting is to overlay all other views in the view controller with a transparent "touch interceptor view". This view's only purposes is to receive all touch messages -- by overriding touchesBegan(), touchesMoved(), touchesEnded() -- and dispatch them to other views as appropriate.

In other words, depending on the type of gesture recognized (tap vs. other), I could call the appropriate target view's (either one of the thumbnails or the map) touchesBegan(), touchesMoved(), touchesEnded() methods directly by forwarding the *touches* and *event* parameter.

Unfortunately, while this works when the target view is a simple UIView, it seems most UIView subclasses (including GMSMapView) don't allow forwarding of touch events in this manner; as described in the following [article](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=74) (see section: A Tempting Non-Solution).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a child of GMSOverlay to the GMSMap? GMSMarker or GMSGroundOverlay?

Comment: Not really. The thumbnails are animated in such a way that they aren't really connected to the map (their frame changes both in size and in position). They kind of float "over" the map. To my knowledge, to animate a GMSMarker or GMSGroundOverlay, I would need to update the map coordinates of the marker but in my case I need to update the screen location of the thumbnail without affecting map coordinates.